# Mongo: How to get document count in cascading relationship

Tags: node.js, mongodb, relationship

I have this collections in mongo:

[image: Collections mongo]

i would like to get the number of forms created in certain agency. currently I first get the users belonging to the agency and then I make another query where I look for all the forms belonging to these users but I would like to know if there is any way to do it in a single query.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `agency` field in your form document and query all forms with the required agency `id`